# Pc freezes at mother board logo

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, power-supply, freeze

My pc freezes at mother board logo and won't take any key input. If i let it standby for a few minutes, it would go to windows repair but even there, I'm unable to press any key to choose an option.

What i tried:

1. removed all usb peripherals before bootup
2. used usb windows bootable
3. removed ram, rubbed the tip with eraser and inserted again

Things I did differently recently:

1. 2 weeks ago, changed new monitor
2. 2 weeks ago, changed mouse/keyboard
3. 1 week ago, changed psu from 600w to 750w
4. 5 days ago, started playing wow
5. 1 day ago, downloaded some pirated app
6. 1 day ago, accidentally leaked my IP address
7. 1 day ago, blue screen and gave me an error "Disk error occured"
8. 1 day ago, whenever I boot it up it immediately goes to the "Disk error occured" error screen.
9. 1 day ago, unplugged the pc and let it rest
10. now, whenever I boot it up it freezes at motherboard logo and unable to press any key

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700
RAM: 8x2 Corsair SK Hynix
GPU: GTX 1050-ti
PSU: generic chinese st-750
Mobo: gigabyte ab350n-gaming
Storage: 128gb ssd sandisk & 1tb hhd western digital

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your boot drive, which I assume is your SSD.

Comment: If its freezing at boot logo, it is definitely NOT a disk error. By boot logo, I assume OP means the motherboard boot logo, which occurs prior/during POST.
OP, do you have any errors occur during POST? You said that it "won't take any input", does this mean you cannot enter the BIOS?
When did the freezes like this start to occur? After the pirated software? It could well be the case that whatever pirated software attempted to flash malware to your BIOS/motherboard firmware but only half succeeded, leading to these issues. Failing this it sounds like hardware failure from the motherboard.

Comment: What if you remove all storage devices (SSD/HDDs) and then boot the system? Does it still freeze at the logo?